# How to write results from snowpark to a table?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am following this code from [github](https://github.com/interworks/Snowflake-Python-Functionality/blob/main/Created%20via%20Snowpark/User%20Defined%20Table%20Functions/Generate%20Auto%20ARIMA%20Predictions.py): it runs a muilti-series time series forecasting using ARIMA. If you want to test, use line 197 to the end.

How can I write the df_output  from line 136 to a snowflake table with partition: append each series result to a table?

I tried using write_pandas from snowpark, but it needs a session.

I also tried loading a sqlalchemy,connection setup using session.add_import(xx.py), but I got warning:

*TypeError: cannot pickle 'sqlalchemy.cprocessors.UnicodeResultProcessor' object: you might have to save the unpicklable object in the local environment first, add it to the UDF with session.add_import(), and read it from the UDF.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

```py
session.write_pandas(pandas_df4, "write_pandas_transient_table", auto_create_table=True)
```

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Session.write_pandas

As you mentioned, it does require a session - as the session is what connects back to Snowflake.

Now looking at the referenced code, this code is generating a UDF. If you look further down, you can see how it's used:

```py
snowpark_session.sql('''
  select * 
  from DEMO_SALES_DATA
    , table(
        SNOWPARK_GENERATE_AUTO_ARIMA_PREDICTIONS(SALE_DATE, SALES) 
        over (
          partition by CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY
          order by SALE_DATE asc
        )
      )
''').show()
```

You can see that there's a `snowpark_session` there you can use to send the results back to a new Snowflake table. Instead of `show()` use `to_pandas()` instead, if you want a Pandas dataframe.

But instead of getting a Pandas dataframe, just use the Snowpark dataframe that the `.sql()` method returns above, and persist it:

```py
df.write.mode("overwrite").save_as_table("saved_table")
```

Comment: Brilliant!!!! Thanks!